# NodeJS Build Package (zip) using Grunt on Jenkins

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to build a package (zip) using grunt in Jenkins (though Jenkins is kind of irrelevant at this stage).

Basically the code is checked out of git, and I run

```
npm install --production
```

but grunt needs the files installed locally.

So I run

```
npm install
```

But now I have all the grunt packages in the node_modules directory.

As part of the grunt build I simply want to copy the node_modules directory into the package.

Am I headed down the right track with trying to package my code using grunt?

Or should I be using grunt to only run jslint, unit tests etc and use this to package:  https://github.com/zeit/pkg

The output is another tool that I will be calling from the command line.